# Is there any way for filter a queryset in django based on two columns? for example |x-10| > 5 and |y-5| > 5

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filter

At the beginning, i am not very good at english. i am sorry. 
I want to filter my result based on absolute of two columns.
I tried so many ways but could not find any useful solution.

```py
# This is my model
class Driver(models.Model):
    account = GenericRelation(Account, related_query_name='drivers')
    rating = models.FloatField()
    x = models.FloatField()
    y = models.FloatField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

# I want filter something like this But :(
drivers = Driver.objects.filter(abs(Driver.y - 5) > 5 and abs(Driver.x - 10) > 5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can first annotate the queryset, and then filter on the annotations. Since [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2) we can use the [**`Abs(..)`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#abs):

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import Abs

drivers = Driver.objects.annotate(
    abs_xy=Abs(F('x') - F('y'))
).filter(abs_xy__gt=5)
```

Here we thus filter the `Driver` objects that have an *|x-y|>5*.

We can also add multiple annotations, like:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import Abs

drivers = Driver.objects.annotate(
    abs_x10=Abs(F('x') - 10),
    abs_y5=Abs(F('y') - 5)
).filter(abs_x10__gt=5, abs_y5__gt=5)
```

This will yield `Driver`s with *|x-10|>5* and *|y-5|>5*.

If the Django version is lower than [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can implement this, like in the [Django-library [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/db/models/functions/math.py#L12):

> ```
> from django.db.models.lookups import Transform
>
> # ...
>
> class Abs(Transform):
>     function = 'ABS'
>     lookup_name = 'abs'
> ```

Comment: i can not use ```from django.db.models.functions import Abs```. instead i use ```from django.db.models import Func``` and for example ```abs_y=Func(F('y') - y, function='ABS')```. thank you Willem Van Onsem